# Можно ли как то сделать уникальным значение в базе данных?

Tags: mysql, триггер

Есть поле в таблице можно ли на уровне базы поставить уникальность на значение. Например по значению 1, то есть ячейка со значением 1 должна быть 1, а остальные значения могут повторяться.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выяснили что можно триггером, вопрос, а как прервать выполнение запроса тригером

```
TRIGGER test.trigger1
 BEFORE INSERT
 ON test
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
тут запрос
END
```

Comment: "Стандартными" средствами вряд ли. Только триггер писать

Comment: на самом деле это нужно ещё и в Pervasive и в mysql, сомневаюсь чтo он триггеры поддерживает, хотя нагуглил что то всё же есть
http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sqlref/syntaxref.03.26.html

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

Answer (score 1):

Можно действительно создать триггер, причем два разных триггера, один на вставку, другой на обновление

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER check_insert_test BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET @block := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE test = 1);
  IF @block >= 1 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INSERT canceled'; 
  END IF;
END//
CREATE TRIGGER check_test BEFORE UPDATE ON test
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET @block := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE test = 1 AND id <> NEW.id);
  IF @block >= 1 AND NEW.test = 1 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'UPDATE canceled'; 
  END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Дальнейшее выполнение запросов можно прервать сигналом при помощи `SIGNAL SQLSTATE`. Сигнал 45000 специально предназначен для пользовательских ошибок, не подлежащих перехвату. Тогда, если в таблице существует запись с `test = 1`, при попытке вставить новую запись с таким же значением, или обновить другую запись, попробовав назначить `test = 1`, вы будет получать сообщения об ошибке

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 1);
ERROR 1644 (45000): INSERT canceled

UPDATE test SET test = 1 WHERE id = 2;
ERROR 1644 (45000): UPDATE canceled
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ с использованием триггера - технически правилен. Но, скажите пожалуйста, для чего вы это делаете в принципе?

Вы считали, какие нагрузки принесет выполнение такого триггера для каждого инсерта?

Создавать такую архитектуру базы данных и даже таблицы - принципиально неправильно. Если какое-то значение уникально, выносите его в отдельное поле.